# which opengl es apis are called in android by unity?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

What are the openGL api's that are called by unity in android or does it use a different graphic architecture? I put logs in all the api's of openGL es at framework in android but none of the logs appear. It seems like it does not use any opengl api's. Any knowledge sharing regarding the call flow from unity to opengl in android is welcome.

Comment: What mechanism are you using to log the OpenGL ES API calls? If your logging involves intercepting java bindings somehow, then you might be missing everything because Unity is most likely making OpenGLES calls from native libraries (i.e. from c++ code).

Comment: @Columbo: I am putting the logs inside opengl/libs/GLES2/gl2_api.in. I suppose every opengl calls should pass through this layer

Comment: I suspect that for logging like that to work, you'd need to recompile Unity itself with those modifications (which you'd need a Unity source code license for). A better bet might be to use a native graphics debugger to capture the OpenGL calls. Android GPU manufacturers each have their own tools, in theory you should be able to install the appropriate GPU profiler for your device and capture the OpenGLES calls that way. In practice, I've always found it agonizingly difficult to get working and tend to do my GPU traces on PC or iOS instead.

Comment: @Columbo:thnx for the comment. One more strange thing what I found is that the unity 3d is not calling "glTexImage2D". If its not calling then how is it updating the texture. Is it doing in its own engine or its not required to call at all

Answer (score 1):

Just get the [Adreno GPU Profiler](https://developer.qualcomm.com/software/adreno-gpu-profiler) and a phone with an Adreno GPU (ex: Galaxy S5) with a Unity based app installed on it then record a GPU trace.

You will then see that Unity is using GLES2 like most other game engines do (could also be GLES3, this depends on Unity version and Phone's GPU).

Note that you may have trouble to catch a glTexImage2D call in the trace because the profiler only records data for one single frame, so you need to be lucky to record a trace at the frame where some textures are created...